# Hide a branch in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch, tfs-security

What I did, is that I have created a group with few members and assigned it to a branch.
When I login with a user from the restricted group, then I don't see any branches.
Then, added that group to the "Readers" group. Now I see all the branches in the project.

Is there a way to hide all other branches and show only the one that has that group?

Thank you

Comment: TFVC or Git?...

Comment: Can you visualize the repository/folder structure and which permissions you applied where?

Comment: @jessehouwing Git

Comment: @jessehouwing Yes, I can visualize repo and permissions in readonly mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers!
I solved it by creating a new project with readonly permissions. So every time there's a change in the main project a task will be triggered in TFS to push the changes to the other project. That was the only option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not support read/contribute permissions on branches. TFVC - yes.

Consider using [Forks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Ok. I might be mistaken then. Probably it's TFVC, because I can set read/contribute permissions.
Thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: The link you referred to is for Azure, but I have TFS installed on my server.
Moreover, I don't even have the option to enable the Forks.

Comment: What version of TFS are you on?

Comment: @VadimVisnevski, according to documentation Forks available from tfs 2018.

Answer (score 0):

In TFVC you can create a new folder in the root and move the restricted branches to it. Then set the Read permission to all root folders (except the new folder) to DENY for the restricted group.

[image]

In this case, the restricted group will see only the new folder and its content.